# How do I pass parameters in PHP unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am trying to learn how to create unit tests for my custom "framework" and here is a method that verifies the email address when user is registering.

```
private function verifyEmail()
{
    if(empty($this->email) || empty($this->email_repeat)) {
        throw new \Exception('please enter email');
    }
    if($this->email != $this->email_repeat) {
        throw new \Exception('emails don\'t match');
    }
    if(!filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        throw new \Exception('E-mail is invalid');
    }

    $isTaken = $this->db->getRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE email = ?", [$this->email]);
    if($isTaken->count > 0){
        throw new \Exception('E-mail is taken');
    }
}
```

And here is the unit test

```
class RegisterTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testVerifyEmail() {
        // what do i type here?
    }
}
```

So, what do I type in the `testVerifyEmail()` method to pass an email to be tested? I am going through the documentation but as a newbie the information is overwhelming and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Don't want to be that guy, but your example is impossible: you simply can't unit test private methods directly. (Technically you can, with closures and reflection, but let's not go down that rabbit hole). If you want to unit test a private method, you have to unit test the public method that invokes the private method. The easiest solution here is to test that public method with a couple of email addresses: null, string, integers, etc. And then you find out that you have smelly code: your verification function actually inserts in a database. You can't unit test that. Or at least you shouldn't.

Comment: You don not should test private methods and your example it does`t right unit test because you have dependency ( database ), this example relative to an integration test suite

Comment: @Loek okay. This is a model so I will try to test the controller instead. Still, how can I send a parameter?

Comment: Testing private methods? You're doing it wrong.

Comment: And on your email validation, you may want to also use `getmxrr()` - the `filter_var()` call will validate the format to RFC specs, but `getmxrr()` makes sure the domain actually exists, etc.

Comment: @ivanivan thanks, I didn't know about this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PhpUnit DataProvider to provide parameters for your test methods.

https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

The example here will execute testMethod 4 times (one for each $data item).

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DataTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider myProvider
     */
    public function testMethod($a, $b, $expected)
    {
        var_dump($a,$b,$expected);

        //... your assertions here
    }

    public function myProvider()
    {
        $data =  [
            //each item represents the related method parameter
            //the first time $a = 'valueOfA-0', $b='valueOfB-0',$expected='valueOfExpected-0' 
            //and so on, for each array
            ['valueOfA-0', 'valueOfB-0', 'valueOfExpected-0'],
            ['valueOfA-1', 'valueOfB-1', 'valueOfExpected-1'],
            ['valueOfA-2', 'valueOfB-2', 'valueOfExpected-2'],
            ['valueOfA-3', 'valueOfB-3', 'valueOfExpected-3'],
        ];

        return $data;
    }
}

//values of testMethod parameters each time
//$a = 'valueOfA-0', $b='valueOfB-0', $expected='valueOfExpected-0'
//$a = 'valueOfA-1', $b='valueOfB-1', $expected='valueOfExpected-1'
//$a = 'valueOfA-2', $b='valueOfB-2', $expected='valueOfExpected-2'
//$a = 'valueOfA-3', $b='valueOfB-3', $expected='valueOfExpected-3'
```

Comment: That's really confusing. You pass it in arrays in another method? But then which key from the array is `$a` and which is `$expected`? https://i.imgur.com/XImiM5M.png

Comment: As you can see in the example each item of the returned array is an array as well. Each item represents the method parameters.

So, if your method needs 2 parameter, each item of the returned array should have 2 item.

However, have a look here, maybe it's clearer 
https://gist.github.com/fcamp/d07e963dbc7aa836d6b45e3937331f33

Comment: Ok I think I got the concept but I don't understand what this is testing. I created a unit test for my `register()` method and when I send a boolean to a parameter expecting a string, the unit test returns OK. Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/SiTnGUVq So, what is wrong?

Comment: @nived you wrote
`$this->assertTrue(true);`

that means you are asserting that true... is true ;)
You are not asserting anything on the parameters you received by DataProvider... nor you are testing your register function at all.

Then remember that the method depending on a data provider, will receive as many parameter as each sub-array in the $data;
So, testRegister should look like 
`testRegister($p1,$p2,$p3,$p4,$p5,$p6,$p7,4p8,$p9)`

I'd advise you to start with some tutorial about phpunit